# Sorting using Linear Linked List in C++

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to build a linear linked list that takes info from users and saves the info in two sorted lists by name (alphabetically) and by birthdate. So far I have

```
struct node{ 
       char* name; 
       int birthDate; 
       node *nameNext; 
       node * dateNext;
  };
```

where each node will have two pointers pointing to the appropriate list. The problem I'm having is how to direct the head pointer node *head. How do I set head when there are two different lists? I'm thinking something like head->nameNext and head->dateNext but that would point to the second node of the lists if it work. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need two heads. But really you want to disentangle the node's from the lists.

Comment: std::sort and std::vector? In 99% of all cases a linked list will be slower anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if i got your question right, you're simply looking to sort your list
in two ways (alphabetically and birthdate) 
note: i will use bubble sort to simplify the algorithm but you can use better one as you know

```
#include <iostream>


struct node{
    const char* name;
    int birthdate;
    node*next;
};

struct sort_data{
private:
    node *name_root = nullptr; // alphabetically head/root pointer
    node *date_root = nullptr; // birthdate head/root pointer
public:
    void push(const char*name,int birthdate); // push data;
    void sort_by_birth(); // sort the birth linked list
    void sort_by_alphabet(); // sort the alphabet linked list
    void print_birth(); // print the data of the birth linked list
    void print_alph(); // print of the data of the alphabet linked list
};


void sort_data::push(const char*name,int birthdata) {
    node*Name = new node; // allocate a node for the alphabet list
    node*Date = new node; // allocate a node for the date list

    Name->name = Date->name = name; 
    Name->birthdate = Date->birthdate = birthdata;
    Name->next = name_root;
    Date->next = date_root;

    name_root = Name;
    date_root = Date;

}

void sort_data::sort_by_birth() {
    node*i = date_root;
    node*j;

    if(!i) // if i == nullptr 
        return;

    while(i){ // while(i!=nullptr)
        j = i->next;
        while(j){
            if(i->birthdate > j->birthdate){
                std::swap(i->birthdate,j->birthdate);
                std::swap(i->name,j->name);
            }
            j = j->next;
        }
        i = i->next;
    }
}

void sort_data::sort_by_alphabet() {

    node*i = name_root;
    node*j;

    if(!i)
        return;

    while(i){
        j = i->next;
        while(j){
            if(i->name[0] > j->name[0]){
                std::swap(i->birthdate,j->birthdate);
                std::swap(i->name,j->name);
            }
            j = j->next;
        }
        i = i->next;
    }
}

void sort_data:: print_birth(){
    node*temp = date_root;

    while(temp){
        std::cout << temp->name << " " << temp->birthdate << std::endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}

void sort_data::print_alph() {

    node*temp = name_root;

    while(temp){
        std::cout << temp->name << " " << temp->birthdate << std::endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

}




int main(){


    sort_data obj;
    obj.push("jack",1997);
    obj.push("daniel",1981);
    obj.push("maria",1995);
    obj.push("john",2008);
    obj.sort_by_alphabet();
    obj.sort_by_birth();
    std::cout << "alphabetically : \n" ;
    obj.print_alph();

    std::cout << "by birthdate : \n";
    obj.print_birth();



}
```

note: because you're using C++ don't use char* to store string literals
use std::string or const char *. as the chars in string literals are const char so you don't want to point on const char with char
if you're using a C++ compiler that support C++11 your compiler should generate a warning about such thing